# Wrong images displaying in winforms listview c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listview

I am working on winforms, where image path and text are being retrieved from SQL Server database and stored in a list. Then they are being added to the listview. I have two button yourvideo and uploadvideo, on clicking yourvideo, listview gets filled from the data and on uploadvideo button, data is inserted in database. If I click on yourvideo, correct info displayed. But when I go to upload and upload a new material to database. Then on clicking yourvideo, new text displayed correctly but the image is same as of the first element of listview. If I rerun the program then correct image appears but the location of image and text will be at random position, not in last.

```
int ccc = -1;
private void xuiSuperButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> paths=new List<string>();
    List<string> title=new List<string>();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title,Thumbnail from RecipeInfo where Username=@username", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Form2.setname);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {           
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           if ((title.Any(item => item == reader[0].ToString()))) continue;
           if ((paths.Any(item => item == $@"{reader[1].ToString()}"))) continue;
           title.Add(reader[0].ToString());
           paths.Add($@"{reader[1].ToString()}");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        messagelabel.Visible = true;
        messagelabel.Text = "Upload videos and share your recipes with others";
   
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
    foreach (string imgpath in paths)
    {
        ListViewItem imagetest = listView1.FindItemWithText(@imgpath);
        if (imagetest == null) 
        {           
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@imgpath));
        }
    }
       
    listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
    foreach (string manhoostitle in title)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText(manhoostitle);
       
        if (item == null ))
        {      
            ccc++;
            listView1.Items.Add(manhoostitle, ccc);
        }
    }
}
```

I used messagebox to check the sequence of images path being retreived, it appears that new image do not get added in last but at random position,while the text appears in last. And on rerunning, the correct image appears with a text but at that random postion.

Comment: Does `if (item == null ))` have and ending curly bracket in the correct spot? Or the SQL missing a order by `where Username=@username ORDER BY Title`

Comment: Obligatory references to [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Are there unique indexes on (Username,Title) and (Username,Thumbnail)? Also because there's no order by clause in your query the rows can come back in a different order each time and, with your title.Any() and path.Any() tests, may lead to different records being displayed each time.